# An explicit form for a solution of a 1st order PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, hyperbolic-equations

I was trying to solve this probleme using the method of differentials :

$\begin{cases} 
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} +u\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = 0  ~~~~~~, (x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^{*}_{+} 
\\u(x,0)= x  ~~~~,
\end{cases}$

where $u=u(x,y)$ ,  since we have :

$\begin{cases} \frac{dx}{1}=\frac{dy}{u} 
\\ du = 0 \end {cases}$

then : $~~~~  u(x,y)= B$   $~~~~$and  $~~~x=\frac{y}{B} +A$

setting : $~~B=f(A)$  $~~~~$ we get : $~~u(x,y)=f(x-\frac{y}{B}) = f(x-\frac{y}{u})$

using the initial condition condition : $~~u(x,0)=f(x) =x$

which means :  $~~u(x,y)= x-\frac{y}{u}$ .

This is the best form I managed to get , is there any other alternative which could possibly lead to an explicit form of $u$ ?

Comment: This is a boundary-value problem for the inviscid Burgers equation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with your general solution : $\quad u=f(x-\frac{y}{u})$

The condition $u(x,0)=x$ determines $f(x)=x$. So, your particular solution fitting the condition is correct (on the form of an implicit equation) :
$$u=x-\frac{y}{u}$$
In order to express it on the explicit form, you have to solve it for $u$:

$u^2-xu+y=0$

$u=\frac12(x\pm\sqrt{x^2+4y})$

With the condition and on $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^{*}_{+}$ the sign of the square root is determined :
$$u(x,y)=\frac12\left(x+\sqrt{x^2+4y}\right)$$